# Pasar Variables de un formulario capturado en javascript a un archivo html

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, javascript-objeto

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema ...

Tengo un formulario en un archivo index.html, que tiene como un action a un archivo welcome.html y envie los parametros por get, Dichos datos fueron capturados en un archivo scripts.js (me los imprime en consola)

Mi problema es , como imprimo en el welcome.html los datos que tengo en las variables del archivo javascript?

aqui les dejo mi codigo del index y scripts.js

no se me permite usar php en el ejercicio y quisiera saber como puedo imprimir dichos datos en mi welcome.html en este archivo tengo solo tablas donde vaa cada campo a imprimir

```js
function mostrarContrasena(){
    var tipo = document.getElementById("password");
    if(tipo.type == "password"){
        tipo.type = "text";
    }else{
        tipo.type = "password";
    }
}


var getData = function(){

    var genero = '';
    var generosr = document.getElementById("sr");
    var generosra = document.getElementById("sra");

    if (generosr.checked) {
        genero = generosr.value;
    }else{
        genero = generosra.value;
    }

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
    var dni = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dni")).value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    
    var si = '';
    var si = document.getElementById("si");
    
    if (si.checked) {
        si = si.value;


    }

    
    document.getElementById("registro").onsubmit();



    
}
```

```html
 <form action="welcome.html" method="get" name="registro" id="form-register">

        <label for="tratamiento">Tratamiento
          <input type="radio" name="genero" id="sr" value="sr">Sr.
          <input type="radio" name="genero" id="sra" value="sra">Sra.
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label for="name"> Nombre
          <input class="controls" type="text" id="name"> 
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label for="surname"> Apellidos
          <input class="controls" type="text" id="surname"> 
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label for="dni"> DNI
          <input class="controls" type="text" id="dni" placeholder="000000000DA"> 
          <p id="ejemplo" class="ejemplo ">Ejemplo: 00000000DA</p>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="email"> Email
          <input class="controls" type="email" id="email"> 
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label for="password"> Contraseña
          <input class="controls" type="password" id="password" name="password"> 
          <button type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasena()">Mostrar</button>
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label for="date"> Fecha de nacimiento
          <input class="controls" type="date" id="date"> 
          <p id="ejemplo1" class="ejemplo1 ">Ejemplo: 31/05/1994</p>
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="si"> Recibir ofertas de nuestros socios</label>
        <input  type="radio" name="si" id="si" value="acepto">
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="getData()">Enviar</button>
      </form>
```

aqui les dejo mi archivo welcome.html con la tabla

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Nombre:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nombrecontenido" id="nombrecontenido">
            </td>
            <td>
                Apellidos:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                DNI:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="dni">
            </td>
            <td>
                EMAIL:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Contrasena;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="passowrd" name="passowrd" id="passowrd">
            </td>
            <td>
                Fecha de nacimiento;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes que usar PHP en el archivo welcome donde recibirá los datos GET del archivo del formulario.

Comment: no puedo hacerlo sin usar php

Comment: No, porque los datos que se pasan en variables GET lo recibe el servidor y el servidor lo prepara para html. Aprende algunos bases de PHP y automáticamente entenderás como se hace.